# Combining two VCF files with differing sampleIds and locations

Tags: pyspark, merge, vcf-variant-call-format

Good day,

How to combine multiple Variant call files (VCF) with differing subjects?

I multiple VCF datasets with differing sampleIds and locations:

file1:

```
contigName |start | end  | names | referenceAllele | alternateAlleles| qual| filters| splitFromMultiAllelic| genotypes
1          |792460|792461|["bla"]|G                |["A"]            |null|["PASS"] |false      | [{"sampleId": "abba", "phased": false, "calls": [0, 0]}]
1          |792461|792462|["blaA"]|G                |["A"]            |null|["PASS"] |false      | [{"sampleId": "abba", "phased": false, "calls": [0, 0]}]
```

file2:

```
contigName |start | end  | names | referenceAllele | alternateAlleles| qual| filters| splitFromMultiAllelic| genotypes
1          |792460|792461|["bla"]|G                |["A"]            |null|["PASS"] |false      | [{"sampleId": "baab", "phased": false, "calls": [0, 0]}]
1          |792464|792465|["blaB"]|G                |["A"]            |null|["PASS"] |false      | [{"sampleId": "baab", "phased": false, "calls": [0, 0]}]
```

I need to combine these to single VCF file. I'm required to work in DataBricks (pyspark/scala) environment due to data security.

[Glow](https://glow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/etl/merge.html) documentation had and idea, which I aped:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
spark.read.format("vcf")\
  .option("flattenInfoFields", True)\
  .load(file_list)\
  .groupBy('contigName', 'start', 'end', 'referenceAllele', 'alternateAlleles', 'qual', 'filters','splitFromMultiAllelic')\
  .agg(F.sort_array(F.flatten(F.collect_list('genotypes'))).alias('genotypes'))\
  .write.mode("overwrite").format("vcf").save(.my_output_destination )
```

This only works when sampleId's are same in both files:

> Task failed while writing rows
>
> Cannot infer sample ids because they are not the same in every row.

I'm considering creating dummy table with NULL calls for all the IDs but that seems silly. (Not to mention huge resource sink.

Is there simple way to combine VCF files with differing sampleIds? Or autofill missing values with NULL calls?

Edit: I managed to do this with bigVCF format. However it autofills -1,-1 calls. I'd like to manually set autofilled values as something more clear that's it's not 'real'

```
write.mode("overwrite").format("bigvcf").save(
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above works if you have identical variants in both tables. I would not recommend using it to combine two distinct datasets as this would introduce batch effects.

The best practice for combining two datasets is to reprocess them from the BAM files to gVCF using the same pipeline. Then run joint-genotyping to merge the samples (instead of a custom spark-sql function).

Databricks does provide a GATK4 best practices pipeline that includes joint-genotyping. Or you can use Deep variant to call mutations.

If it is not possible to reprocess the data, then the two datasets should be treated separately in a meta-analysis, as opposed to merging the VCFs and performing a mega-analysis.